# renaming column returns str object has no attribute 'rename'

Tags: pandas

```
df3.rename(columns={'Impressions': 'Impressions Served'}, inplace=True)
df3.rename(columns={'Impressions': 'Impressions Served'}, inplace=True)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-6cd7fcf0d1d0> in <module>()
----> 1 df3.rename(columns={'Impressions': 'Impressions Served'}, inplace=True)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'rename'
```

Can you tell me why I'm having this error and how to change the name of the column in my df?

Comment: Type df3.__class__

Comment: Please share `df3` definition. 
In any case use: `df3 = pandas.DataFrame()`

Comment: Could you please share a minimal, reproducible example (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This will help folks on SO help you debug your issue.

Answer (score 1):

`df3` is not of type `pandas.DataFrame`, it is a string. Therefore your issue is with whatever code creates the `df3` variable. If you share a minimal reproducible version of the code that creates `df3` then you might get help fixing that issue.